# "Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired."

Tags: package-management

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 over 10.04. It seemed to go OK until I tried running my updates. When I launch Software Center I get the following error message:

> **Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired. Do you want to repair it now?**
>
> Once Update Manager has finished the repairs, you can close it and return to the store.

So I hit <kbd>repair</kbd> and then I get this message:

> Package operation failed
>
> The installation or removal of a software package failed.

So I hit <kbd>OK</kbd> and it goes back to the first error message

And it just continues repeating those two messages. How do I fix whatever is broken? I reviewed answers for similar questions. I tried the suggestions in that link but they did not work. I tried to post the results but, being new to this system I am not allowed to post more than 2 links. However, it seems the crux of the problem is this:

```
(Reading database ... 742676 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libxml-libxml-perl ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libxml-libxml-perl.prerm: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libxml-libxml-perl.prerm: update-perl-sax-parsers: not found
dpkg: error processing libxml-libxml-perl (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxml-libxml-perl
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend doing a clean installation. I don't have deep knowledge on this, but I think that you should delete all of the PPAs that you had registered before.

Then, run `sudo apt-get update` and reboot.

After rebooting, run `sudo apt-get update` again and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

If this doesn’t work, I think that there are programs that could be useful to remake your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

When is a big update like that, I always recommend format HDDs and install all from 0, and with more reason if we are talking about Linux.

You can edit the two last lines of your /etc/apt/sources.list

And,

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That will update your system software list.

And then,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That should fix your packages.

If it doesn't, then you've got a broken package manager, and I'd recommend reinstalling - but only if you've tried everything else!!!

Also:

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update your package list. Then

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to clean up any partial packages. Then

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to clean up the apt cache.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will clean up any unneeded dependencies. If while doing this you can identify the broken package this code will very forcefully remove it.

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package name
```

Change package name to the real name of course.

Regards!

Comment: Does this mean the broken package is libxml-libxml-perl? And if so, is it safe to remove that package with force?                                                                                                                 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.10.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libxml-sax-perl but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: I think it is safe, but I can't test it. In any case, you know what you do, and how repair it, reinstalling what you forced to remove.

Comment: Running sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package name I got this error dpkg: error: conflicting actions -f (--field) and -r (--remove)