# Bugged software center catalog - dep paradox

Tags: dependencies

I had not installing any packages recently, but when i launched Software center, I saw a message: "Item cannot be installed or removed..."

/i am translating dumps from foreign language, so it might be not super precise with original/

[Fixing software center catalog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30993/fixing-software-center-catalog)

[Items cannot be installed or removed in 12.04 over 10.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318035/items-cannot-be-installed-or-removed-in-12-04-over-10-4)

those solutions didnt work at all. I have some kind of paradox:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

tells me, that 2 packages will be installed:
libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libnspr4:i386
(and there is need to download 0 B/217 kB of archives) - strange; *why it needs i386 deps in x64 arch system anyway?*

I choose Y and it dumps:

```
(Reading database ... 300571 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 (from .../libdbus-glib-1-2_0.98-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: processing error /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbus-glib-1-2_0.98-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libdbus-glib-1-2/changelog.Debian.gz' is different from the same file on the system
Missing report of program apport, becouse MaxReports limit reached
Unpacking libnspr4:i386 (from .../libnspr4_4.9.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: processing error /var/cache/apt/archives/libnspr4_4.9.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/doc/libnspr4/changelog.Debian.gz' is different from the same file on the system
Missing report of program apport, becouse MaxReports limit reached
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Interrupted stream)
There were errors while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbus-glib-1-2_0.98-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnspr4_4.9.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

therefore I've removed `/var/cache/` folder just in case; 
then tried to install required deps independently:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
```

dumped:

```
You need to use "apt-get -f install", to repair following problems:
Following packages has broken dependencies:
 libnss3:i386 : Requires: libnspr4:i386 (>= 4.8.6) but it will be not installed
E: Broken dependencies. Please try use "apt-get -f install" without packages (or give a solution).
```

so then I did:

```
sudo apt-get install libnspr4:i386
```

and it dumped:

```
You need to use "apt-get -f install", to repair following problems:
Following packages has broken dependencies:
 libgconf-2-4:i386 : Requires: libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 (>= 0.78) but it will be not installed
E: Broken dependencies. Please try use "apt-get -f install" without packages (or give a solution).
```

both needs each one to allow install other one? paradox? i am in mess.

*ps, if no solutions will be found to this I can copy packages from other working mirror pc /just dont want to clone whole partition/, which folder is used for storing this packages?*

Comment: ye, thanks for help... I've restored whole root partition..... and it didnt help lol! the problem must be somewhere in home partition

Answer (score 0):

I have watched over folder by folder, file by file and found it! It was `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file.

I have restored it, and Software Center was miraculously cured.

/ps. restoring whole root partition didn't worked because I forgot that I've put var folder into other partition and ln to it ;)

Comment: warrning: not perfect solution... it turned out that i had differences in modules in both mirrored pc's, and now i cant get into admin account.. even login screen becouse loading display modules failure........... but software center catalog is working ha ha ah HAHAHA .. ..  cry